# How to read String from console with VC?

Tags: c, visual-c++, command-line, mfc

I want to read string from command line. I open some program which run in command line and I have to wait for that program process. So , I don't know when process success .I can't type next command if can't read string from command. This is my code for run program unhidden.bat in command and send Y for process.

```
DWORD WINAPI unhidden(LPVOID lp)
{
   //ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:/unhidden.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    system("C:/unhidden.bat");
   return 0;
}

int run_unhidden(){
    AllocConsole() ;
    AttachConsole( GetCurrentProcessId() ) ;
    freopen( "CON", "w", stdout ) ;

    HANDLE hConIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD dwTmp;

    INPUT_RECORD ir[5];

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, unhidden,(LPDWORD)0, 0, &dwTmp);

    Sleep( 1000 );

    ir[0].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = 'y';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = 'Y';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('Y', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[1].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = VK_RETURN;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_RETURN;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[2].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = FALSE;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = VK_RETURN;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_RETURN;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);



    dwTmp = 0;
    WriteConsoleInput(hConIn, ir, 2, &dwTmp);

wprintf(GetCommandLine());

    Sleep( 1000 );



    ir[0].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = 'y';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = 'Y';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('Y', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[1].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = VK_RETURN;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_RETURN;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);


    ir[2].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = FALSE;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = VK_RETURN;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_RETURN;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

     dwTmp = 0;
    WriteConsoleInput(hConIn, ir, 3, &dwTmp);
    wprintf(GetCommandLine());
     Sleep( 1000 );
```

it show like this in console

```
Do you want to process now (Y/N)?y "C:\Users\PKRU\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Virus Scan\Debug\Virus Scan .exe" You chose: y 
Please wait . . . 
"C:\Users\PKRU\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Virus Scan\Debug\Virus Scan .exe" Could Not Find N:\*.lnk 
N:\autorun.ini\*, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

How to read line

> N:\autorun.ini*, Are you sure (Y/N)?

with MFC for send next key to console . If I can't know when it will show this line then I can't send Y or N to program

Comment: can't see any MFC in your code

Comment: Use [ReadConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use `CreateProcess()` instead of `system()`.
It works fine on Windows. You can run the bat file with cmd.